# Whitespaces in svg text in Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, whitespace, snap.svg

I am trying to append/write text in svg through Snap.svg. The code below works fine in chrome, firefox, opera and edge, but not working in Internet Explorer. I have tried putting charset as utf8 in meta tag inside html file but it's still not working.

If lines2 is passed as an argument then internet explorer consider   as normal string.

```
     var lines1 = ["a            b", "c   d", "e f"];
     var lines2 = ["a&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;b", "c   d", "e f"];
        Snap("#svg").text(10, 0, lines).attr({
            fill: "black",
            fontSize: "18px"
        }).selectAll("tspan").forEach(function(tspan, i) {
           tspan.attr({
                 x: 0,
                 dy: 20
           });
           tspan.node.innerHTML = tspan.node.textContent.replace(/ /g,'&nbsp;');
       });
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/295v6vek/1/) link for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `innerHTML` on SVG elements is not universally supported.  Only really for the latest browser versions.

Use `textContent`, and instead of the HTML Latin1 entity, use the  the unicode character equivalent of nbsp instead (ASCII 160).

```js
var lines = ["a            b", "c   d", "e f"]
Snap("#svg").text(10, 0, lines).attr({
  fill: "black",
  fontSize: "18px"
}).selectAll("tspan").forEach(function(tspan, i) {
  tspan.attr({
    x: 0,
    dy: 20
  });
  tspan.node.textContent = tspan.node.textContent.replace(/ /g,'\u00a0');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<svg id='svg'></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">`

maybe my solution will be helpful try to add this doctype declaration, to solve your issue with Internet Explorer.